# pasara datos de un componente a otro en angular 9

Tags: angular, firebase

buenas tardes tengo el sigueinte problema, tengo un formulario en un compenente angular 9 donde hay una tabla con ciertos datos y dos botones, el boton editar redirecciona a otro formulario donde los inputs deben autocompletarse con los tados de la tabla y otrso que no se muestran en la misma, para ser editados, el problema es que no se como pasar esos datos desde un componente a otro...

html de la tabla donde esta la funcion que abre el fomulario

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Gestionar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-info" *ngFor="let dato of datos">
                    <td>{{ dato.titulo }}</td>
                    <!-- <td>{{ dato.contenido }}</td> -->
                    <td align="center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="abrirEditar(dato)">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pen-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"/>
                          </svg>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="eliminar(dato)">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v7a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-7z"/>
                          </svg>
                      </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

en su .ts esta la funcion que abre la ruta del formulario

```
abrirEditar(dato: posteoModel) {
    
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/editar-publicacion');
    
  }
```

fomulario que recibe los datos del formulario anterior y que deberia auntocompletarse

```
<form [formGroup]="editPostForm" (ngSubmit)="editarPublicacion(editPostForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Titulo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" formControlName="titulo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Contenido</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" formControlName="contenido"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Seleccionar Imagen</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" formControlName="imagen" (change)="handleImage($event)">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publicar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancelar()">Cancelar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

.ts que deberia del formulario anterior

```
export class EditarPublicacionComponent implements OnInit {

  private image: any;
  private imageOriginal: any;

  @Input() post: posteoModel;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router, private postService: PosteoService) { 
      console.log(this.post);
    }


  public editPostForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    titulo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    contenido: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    imagen: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  editarPublicacion(posteo: posteoModel) {
    console.log('imagen', this.image);
    console.log('imagen', this.imageOriginal);
    if (this.image == this.imageOriginal) {
      posteo.imagen = this.imageOriginal;
      this.postService.editPostById(posteo);
    } else {
      this.postService.editPostById(posteo, this.image);
    }
  }

   public initValuesForm(): void {
     this.editPostForm.patchValue({
       id: this.post.id,
       titulo: this.post.titulo,
       contenido: this.post.contenido
     });
     console.log(this.editPostForm);
   }

  handleImage(event: any): void {
    this.image = event.target.files[0];
  }

  cancelar() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/publicar');
  }

  volver() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/publicar');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero crea un observable que te almacene los datos que quieres editar en tu formulario.

```
      import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

      @Injectable({
         providedIn: 'root'
      })
      export class PersistenceDataSourceService {

            constructor() { }

            private dataPercistenceSource = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
            public dataPercistence = this.dataPercistenceSource.asObservable();

            updateDataPersistence(dataToEdit: any){
               this.dataPercistenceSource.next(dataToEdit);
            }
      }
```

Ya teniendo el observable, tienes que instanciar este servicio al .ts de tu componente dende está la tabla.

```
        constructor(private persistenceDataService: PersistenceDataSourceService) {}
```

En tu funcion del evento click del boton agrega lo siguiente:

```
          abrirEditar(dato: posteoModel) { // Estoy suponiendo que dato es lo que quieres mandar al siguiente componente y es un JSON
             this.persistenceDataService.updateDataPersistence(dato); // agregado
             this.router.navigateByUrl('/editar-publicacion');

          }
```

Dentro del componente donde está tu formulario de igual forma debes hacer la instancia para usar el servicio y suscribirte al observable para obtener el valor que almacenaste. En el constructor o en el onInit grega lo siguiente:

```
         this.persistenceDataService.dataPercistence
             .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe((data) => {
           this.datosParaFormulario = data;
           // aquí ya puedes inicializar el formulario con la info que trae data.
         })
```

no te olvides de desuscribirte al observable una vez que se destruya el componente.